# Button not expanding in Android

Tags: android, button, android-orientation

I have the following code for my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/nav_text_size" >
            </TextView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen31"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/TA1"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen32"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/TA2"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen33"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/TA3"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen34"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/TA4"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
            </Button>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="@color/line_color" >
            </View>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/copyright"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem with this is that when I turn my phone to landscape, the buttons don't expand and fill only half of the screen.

How can I get my buttons to expand to fill the rest of the screen?

Comment: Can you post screenshot?

Comment: "tried many options",what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons are ok, but their parent(Linear Layout) isn't as big as the screen because its width is set to wrap_content. Just change to match_parent and you will be ok.

**match_parent** = Sets the dimension to match that of the parent element. Added in API Level 8 to deprecate fill_parent.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What about making your `LinearLayout` width set to `match_parent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/background_color"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/nav_text_size" >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen31"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/TA1"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen32"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/TA2"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen33"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/TA3"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ProceedToScreen34"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_name"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/TA4"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="@color/line_color" >
        </View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/copyright"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

set android layout width to fill parent as :

```
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

remember , whetever you want to fit to screen width fully , set its layout width to fill_parent

Comment: `fill_parent` is deprecated. You should use `match_parent` instead

Comment: set the layout_width of " Linear Layout "  as fill_parent .. okay,,

Comment: Even on the `LinearLayout` you should still use `match_parent` though.

Answer (score 0):

create a folder called **layout-land** Now create a layout in the same name of the layout which u have created for portrait, with the same id for each component in the landscape mode. Since you're working it the folder "layout-land" your screen will be in landscape mode . Design the layout as per your requirement . Now when u change the modes of display , android will shift between modes of display . Thank you . Have fun